# Xcode 4 workspace, cross-referencing files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, workspace

I am currently switching from developing two separate Xcode Projects into using Xcode workspace. And thus have a question.

After I import two of my projects into workspace, how do I tell one project to search for files in another project?

What I would like to accomplish is to get rid of duplicate classes that are the same for both project and keep them only in one project.

Example. In project A I have a class `Book` I would like to use this class in project B but not to be forced to actually have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two propositions, I am assuming your project A and B are two iOS applications :

- Share files accross projects

  *(just reference files, do not copy, should use a common/ folder to stay clean and safe)*
- Create a static library referenced by both projects *(more complex...)*

Comment: Sharing files across project by referencing files is ok, but how to distinguish which files are referenced and which are not?

Comment: You can from Xcode by checking path (marked as relative)... But that's why I strongly suggest that if you choose this option to cleanly separate files like three folders : `ProjectA/`, `ProjectB/`, `Common/` or you will quickly end in a horrible mess :) You can also grep `.pbxproj` Xcode project files, that's just `XML`.

Comment: you're welcome, I wish that one day static library (or any similar solution) will be easier to work with... Workspaces are supposed to bring some ease... Not convinced yet.

Comment: Thanks for the tips about referencing files. It's much less headache than trying to figure out how to link this and that using Xcode workspace :)

Comment: @pixelfreak workspaces is a good concept intended to solve this. But a non-working one = useless :( *no one ever seen the **magical auto linking** (or even manual) it is supposed to do I think...*

Comment: @VincentGuerci : im using workspace, but my concern is how to access other viewcontrollers object into other project's viewcontroller in Xcode works space, im worrying about this issue from past few days, its would great help for me.