# How to call among xcode project within workspace?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on multiple projects in a workspace, i am having project A and project B,i am able to build and run both projects separately,now i want to run project A and from there while executing it should call project B and execute it, how to do it?

Comment: You mean debugging 2 projects at the same time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you clarify "it should call project B" because that could mean a lot of things. If you mean there is a common functionality shared by Project A and Project B then [this thread might answer your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354945/xcode-4-workspace-cross-referencing-files)

Basically you should either:

1) Create a common folder and reference the files in this folder from project A and B (easier)

or

2) Create a static library referenced by both projects (more complicated)

Comment: after project A gets executed, it should start executing project B, is it possible to do like this?, i am a newbie so i get confused to create aggregate target, ,how to use it? and run multiple projects in workspace, can you please suggest me any links to guide me?